# Where to put "quests" in a material design

Tags: menu, material-design

I don't know if there's a common term for it, but I call them "quests" - goals that the system gives a user to help guide them through the interface the first time.

How should they be prioritized in the display?  Above or below the menu bar?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean onboarding. [Here you have some insight](https://www.materialup.com/posts/onboarding-process-for-google-app-on-ios) from Google's designer Michael Oh about the new onboarding process obviously designed with Material.

If you take a closer look to the images in that post, you'll see he's simply using sheets. I think you should have a more complete view if you check the official **Material Design's Patterns**, obviously starting by [App Structure](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/app-structure.html), but I think you'll find what you're looking for on the [Notifications](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-behavior), [Launch Screens](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/launch-screens.html) and [Empty States](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/empty-states.html) sections

Comment: Thanks Devin!  I looked over those links, and I think the "quests" I'm using here are slightly different than just onboarding.  The quests are per-user objectives that give rewards when their conditions are met.

They are used at the beginning as part of a series of tutorial quests, filling the same function as onboarding.

But they're also assigned to a user from other sources -- like quests that you get as a result of performing certain actions on the site, and "daily quests" that are assigned to users randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to the popular [**ShowCaseView**](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView). Used in many apps for the first launch tour of the application, putting a 50% opacity overlay over the elements which aren't in focus to concentrate, and keeping the element to tour in focus.

[image: ShowcaseView]

You could cover the entire screen (except the Status and Nav bar) with them and focus the element you want the user to concentrate on. Brilliant tool!